# Pandas MultiIndex: How to remove entire level that has zero positive values in specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this Pandas MultiIndex:

[image]

Is there a trivial way, I can remove any level, if there are no positive values in the column `INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT`. In the example Image, this would completely remove the `AAPL` level.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `DataFrame` for better testing:

```
print df
           INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF  INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT
SYMBOL                                                      
AAL    0                   0.000000                 0.000000
       1                  -0.010875                 0.000000
       2                  -0.003659                 0.000000
       3                   0.007364                 0.000000
       4                  -0.018224                 0.000000
       5                   0.015290                 0.000000
       6                   0.067060                27.360990
       7                   0.028754                11.732043
       8                   0.021312                 0.000000
       9                   0.083284                33.980826
       10                  0.073214                29.872141
AAPL   0                   0.000000                 0.000000
       1                  -0.032254                 0.000000
       2                  -0.050695                 0.000000
       3                  -0.009713                 0.000000
       4                  -0.000673                 0.000000
       5                  -0.021018                 0.000000
AAPL1  6                  -0.061908                 0.000000
       7                  -0.029942                -1.000000
       8                  -0.074356                -1.000000
       9                  -0.154641                 0.000000
       10                 -0.137246                 0.000000
ADBE   0                   0.000000                 2.000000
       1                   0.000000                 0.000000
       2                   0.000000                 0.000000
```

```
idx=df[~(df['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT']<=0).values].index.get_level_values('SYMBOL').unique()
print idx
['AAL' 'ADBE']

print df.loc[(idx, slice(None)),:]
           INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF  INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT
SYMBOL                                                      
AAL    0                   0.000000                 0.000000
       1                  -0.010875                 0.000000
       2                  -0.003659                 0.000000
       3                   0.007364                 0.000000
       4                  -0.018224                 0.000000
       5                   0.015290                 0.000000
       6                   0.067060                27.360990
       7                   0.028754                11.732043
       8                   0.021312                 0.000000
       9                   0.083284                33.980826
       10                  0.073214                29.872141
ADBE   0                   0.000000                 2.000000
       1                   0.000000                 0.000000
       2                   0.000000                 0.000000
```

Explanation:

```
#use inverted by(~) condition (<= 0) for column INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT
print ~(df['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'] <= 0)
SYMBOL    
AAL     0     False
        1     False
        2     False
        3     False
        4     False
        5     False
        6      True
        7      True
        8     False
        9      True
        10     True
AAPL    0     False
        1     False
        2     False
        3     False
        4     False
        5     False
AAPL1   6     False
        7     False
        8     False
        9     False
        10    False
ADBE    0      True
        1     False
        2     False
Name: INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT, dtype: bool
```

```
#find all rows which contains at least one positive values in column INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT
print df[~(df['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'] <= 0).values]
           INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF  INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT
SYMBOL                                                      
AAL    6                   0.067060                27.360990
       7                   0.028754                11.732043
       9                   0.083284                33.980826
       10                  0.073214                29.872141
ADBE   0                   0.000000                 2.000000
```

```
#find all index value in level SYMBOL
print df[~(df['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'] <= 0).values].index.get_level_values('SYMBOL')
Index([u'AAL', u'AAL', u'AAL', u'AAL', u'ADBE'], dtype='object', name=u'SYMBOL')

#get unique values of index
idx = df[~(df['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'] <= 0).values].index.get_level_values('SYMBOL').unique()
print idx
['AAL' 'ADBE']

#select all unique values
print df.loc[(idx, slice(None)),:]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, great help!

Comment: The structure you provided was the missing piece.

Had tried a similar attempt using using sum() instead, but this is much better!

`sum_res = mi_res.groupby(level=['SYMBOL']).sum()
    sum_res_index = sum_res[sum_res['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'] > 0].index.tolist()
    mi_res_constrained = mi_res.iloc[mi_res.index.get_level_values('SYMBOL').isin(sum_res_index)]`

Comment: Sorry,  I think better is use instead of picture text, because people of StackOverflow hate questions with pictures of code - this cannot be easy copied to their text editors and you get vote downs. So in your next question you can use rather text. But it is up to you, it is only small advice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll give that a go in future!

Comment: Could this solution be adapted to sort the multi-index by the values in 'INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'?

Comment: I dont understand - what do you think `by the values in 'INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'` ? Column `INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT` is not ordered. Can you explain more?

Comment: I want to re-order levels in the MultiIndex by the maximum value in the `INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT` column, so if `AAL` has a maximum value of 10.0 and `AAPL` has a maximum value of 20.0, `AAPL` would be first in the multi-index. Should I open a separate question?

Comment: I tried this: `data_nasdaq_top_100_preprocessed_merge_mi_res_net_constrained.sort(['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'], ascending=False)` but this sorts every row in the MultiIndex so all the rows for `AAPL` are no longer together

Comment: I think you can open new question. Try add only `5-6` rows of data and desired output of sample.

Comment: If you want, you can upvote this answer too. Thank you.